# .htaccess Authentification asked in the wrong page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

On my website, I have a page which ask an authentication called admin page. The thing is that now when I go to my home page, it asks me to authenticate. Even if I put my login password and hit Log in, it doesn't work and keep showing the authentication modal. In the apache log, I have the following error :

```
[Wed Jul 08 11:04:21.319601 2015] [auth_basic:error] [pid 32527] [client 192.168.1.133:54379] AH01618: user flavien not found: /
```

Which is weird because the user flavien exists and the authenticate was working before. 
The code in the .htaccess file in the admin page is :

```
AuthUserFile /home/valentin/workspace/www.mysite.com/app/admin/.htpasswd
#AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Restricted Access"
AuthType Basic
<limit GET>
require valid-user
</Limit>
```

and in the .htpasswd there is `flavien:mypassword`

Any idea of what can cause this problem?

Comment: Does apache have access to `/home/valentin/workspace/www.mysite.com/app/admin/.htpasswd` ?

Comment: The other thing is, what if I spoof my request to be POST instead of GET? Do I get authenticated?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Apache has access to `/home/valentin/workspace/www.mysite.com/app/admin/.htpasswd`. And when I change GET to POST I get a page which don't even load.

Comment: Do you remember the last thing that you've done before the problem exist?

Comment: I have done some modifications HTML/CSS modifications on the home page. And even after that, it still worked until this morning.

Comment: Hi.

First of all, please do not use <Limit GET> since it could permit to a malicious user to have access to your admin. (eg : GETAAAA .../admin is treated as a GET request because invalid, but bypass LIMIT clause).

Where is your .htaccess is really located? At the root of the admin folder?

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for the advice. 
Yes the .htaccess is located at the root of the admin folder. And .htpassword too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my problem. In fact I have copied the .htaccess at ../www.mysite.com to get a backup and by deleting it it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **htpasswd** command to correctly generate a user for your .htpasswd. Syntax is as follow :

```
htpasswd /path/to/your/.htpasswd username
```

That will prompt you a password.

For your error, I don't think Apache is accepting plain password in .htpasswd, excepting on Windows. Maybe I'm in error with that.

Comment: Thanks for your response but it is actually not what I was looking for.